# Have some tag wiki gone missing?

Tags: discussion, support

I could have sworn I got reputation for the dfsr tag wiki and dfsr was merged with dfs-r recently too. Now the tag appears empty.

I also believe the Kerberos tag had data but now doesn't. I have proposed some tag wiki content for it.

I wont check all my tags but will be disappointed if time spent getting some useful in them has disappeared.

Just wondering if there are any known issues with tag wiki content going AWOL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens, there is a mod-only tool called "Orphan Wikis"

https://serverfault.com/admin/orphan-wikis

And in that list I do see one for DFS:

https://serverfault.com/posts/292561/revisions

So yes! Wikis do go missing when tags are merged. About the only thing we can do about that is to take the content of the merged tag and copy it into the merge target; but that means the wiki-credit goes to the moderator doing the merge not the person who made it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not fussed about reputation or any credit. I'd settle for just having the information. I'd just hate to type information again.